# How to use multiple styles in material ui withStyles() React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have the following:

```
const styles = theme => ({root: {backgroundColor: '#000000'})
const styles2 = theme => ({root: {backgroundColor: '#fff'})
```

on my react component I have 
export default compose(
  withStyles(**styles**, {withTheme: true}),

I need to determine what style to use in render() what is the best way to do that ?

Comment: make the style in state and give that state on your component props then start changing the state value it will rerender your component

Comment: Is there a way to determine what style I use while passing a props variable on theme style ?

Comment: if you mean what background color should be when idle, focusing or selected you get an args in the withStyle to determine it but if you want to change the color for a business condition then try to make the color as a state means make the backGround color as a state and pass the state to the theme background value

Answer (score 0):

After long investigation the best solution I came with is as follows:

I have imported classNames [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Used only one style

```
const styles = theme => ({
  whiteRoot: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  blackRoot: {
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
  },
})
```

and on render()
for example

```
<Grid container className={classNames(classes[`${black}Root`])} justify='center'>
```

and worked fine